# How to find child of a GameObject or the script attached to child GameObject via script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know this is a bit of a stupid question, but how would I reference the child (a cube) of a game object via script(the script is attached to the gameObject). (the equivalent to something like GetComponent)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

**Finding child GameObject by index**:

You can get the first child of a GameObject with the [`GetChild`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html) function.

```
GameObject originalGameObject = GameObject.Find("MainObj");
GameObject child = originalGameObject.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
```

You can get other children by providing index number of the child GameObject such as 1,2,3, to the [`GetChild`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html) function.

> and if its a child of a child in the original gameobject? would I just
> have to repeat it or would it just be the nth one down

You find the child first, then find the child of that child from the reference.

Let's say this is OriginalGameObject/Prefab hierarchy:

- OriginalGameObject
- child1
- child2
- child3

  - childOfChild3

As you can see the `OriginalGameObject` is the parent of `child1`, `child2` and `child3`. childOfChild3 is the child of `child3`.

Let's say you want to access the `childs` and you only have reference to `OriginalGameObject` which is the parent GameObject:

```
//Instantiate Prefab
GameObject originalGameObject  = Instantiate(prefab);

//To find `child1` which is the first index(0)
GameObject child1 = originalGameObject.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;

//To find `child2` which is the second index(1)
GameObject child2 = originalGameObject.transform.GetChild(1).gameObject;

//To find `child3` which is the third index(2)
GameObject child3 = originalGameObject.transform.GetChild(2).gameObject;
```

The index starts from `0` so the real index number is `index-1` just like arrays.

Now, to get the reference of `childOfChild3` which is the child of `child3` but you only have reference to `OriginalGameObject` which is the parent GameObject:

First of all, get reference of `child3` then get `childOfChild3` from it.

```
GameObject mychild = originalGameObject.transform.GetChild(2).gameObject;
GameObject childOfChild3 = mychild.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
```

**Finding [all] child GameObject by index with loop**:

To loop through all the child of originalGameObject:

```
GameObject originalGameObject = Instantiate(prefab);
for (int i = 0; i < originalGameObject.transform.childCount; i++)
{
    GameObject child = originalGameObject.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;
    //Do something with child
}
```

You can also find child by name with the `transform.FindChild` function. I wouldn't recommend that you can do that. It seems slow and will conflict when multiple child share the-same name. That's why you use `GetChild`.

**Finding child GameObject by name**:

```
GameObject child1 = originalGameObject.transform.FindChild("child1").gameObject;
GameObject child2 = originalGameObject.transform.FindChild("child2").gameObject;
GameObject child3 = originalGameObject.transform.FindChild("child3").gameObject;
```

To find `childOfChild3`, you can easily do that with the '`/`' just like you do with a file directory. You provide the `parent/child` then name. The parent of `childOfChild3` is `child3`. So, we use, `childOfChild3/child3` in FindChild function.

```
GameObject childOfChild3 = originalGameObject.transform.FindChild("child3/childOfChild3").gameObject;
```

**Finding scripts/components attached to child GameObject**:

If all you want is the script that is attached to the child GameObject, then use [`GetComponentInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html):

```
MyScript childScript = originalGameObject.GetComponentInChildren<MyScript>();
```

If there are more than one child with the-same script and you just want to get **all** the scripts attached to them, then use [`GetComponentsInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html):

```
MyScript[] childScripts = originalGameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<MyScript>();
for (int i = 0; i < childScripts.Length; i++)
{
    MyScript myChildScript = childScripts[i];
    //Do something with myChildScript
}
```

Comment: Programmer, only the first??

Comment: Check the update. You said a child not a children so I assumed there is only one child. The answer/code provided by [Knetic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40752121/3785314) should not even compile on Unity 5.

Comment: and if its a child of a child in the original gameobject? would I just have to repeat it or would it just be the nth one down

Comment: wait actually so would there be a way?

Comment: Hold on a momenet. I am editing my answer to answer that.

Comment: Check my update. I think you should edit the body of your question and explain your question more.

Comment: It seems `Transform.FindChild(string n)` is deprecated and replaced with `Transform.Find(string n)`.

Answer (score 1):

I find this very short method just 2 line,
my player hierarchy is like this:

-Player

1. Head
2. BulletPos

Code:

```
Transform[] ObjectChildrens;
ObjectChildrens = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
GameObject Head = System.Array.Find(ObjectChildrens, p => p.gameObject.name == "Head").gameObject;


GameObject BulletPos = System.Array.Find(ObjectChildrens, p => p.gameObject.name == "BulletPos").gameObject;
GameObject LifeProgresBar = System.Array.Find(ObjectChildrens, p => p.gameObject.name == "LifeProgresBar").gameObject.GetComponent<Text>().text = "100";
CapsuleCollider2D cc = System.Array.Find(ObjectChildrens, p => p.gameObject.name == "HeadPlace").gameObject.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider2D>();
```

Answer (score 0):

`gameObject.transform.children` contains all immediate children of a given GameObject. You can iterate over it and find the desired child. For instance, by name;

```
for(int i = 0; i < gameObject.transform.childCount;)
{
    if(gameObject.transform.children[i].name == "someName")
    {
        // do what you need with it
    }

}
```

There are a few ways to iterate. You can use an enumerable, as indicated in [these docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html), or use [FindChild](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html).

Usually you'll want to iterate over children if you have some other criteria, such as wanting to find a child which has a specific type of Component, rather than just by name.

Comment: thanks a lot, I can first accept this answer in 11 mins but don't worry, I will...

Comment: just one thing though, are you sure there wouldn't be an easier way

Comment: I just now updated with a couple convenience methods for finding by name, and some notes about when you'd want to iterate over children vs use `FindChild`

Answer (score -3):

You could have public variable in parent gameObject.

`public Tranform childGameObject;`

and then assign your child gameObject to it.

This way you avoid hidden dependencies. As well as your child cube can be inside of another parent and another parent.

Comment: gabs, this wouldn't work as the game object is being instantiated and i need a reference to the child of that instance