# How to add nested transform to list instead of transfom of the parent gameObject?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make the trajectories for enemies like list of gameObjects transforms. [image: 1]

And i want to add `Path` gameObject with all points of trajectory. And when i try to attach trajectory to enemy, i want to attach list of transforms, but instead that i attach the transform of the parent Path object.

[image: 2]

How to unwrap points transforms in the list?

I've tried to google my issue, but i saw only nested prefabs and nothing about my problem

Comment: So you want all enemies to be under 1 parent? I don’t fully understand.

Comment: This should answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40752083/how-to-find-child-of-a-gameobject-or-the-script-attached-to-child-gameobject-via

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find child of a GameObject or the script attached to child GameObject via script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40752083/how-to-find-child-of-a-gameobject-or-the-script-attached-to-child-gameobject-via)